# UIView will not change size

Tags: objective-c

i have some container view, which i manage to change his size with animation.
Problem is, when i want to turn it back to the original size, nothing happens.

Here is the code to change it first time (works great)

```
//ANIMATE CONTAINER
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;
    //mainContainerView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.45
                     animations:^{mainContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {

        //change container subview
         [self switchToViewWithViewName:view  AndTransition:kCATransitionFromBottom];

    }];
```

//than next time does not work-he stay at the same size

```
   CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    mainContainerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 455);
```

Comment: Add logging to see what `screenRect` and `mainContainerView.frame` are to start with, the second time. I'm guessing you are changing the `frame` to the value it already has, so nothing happens. Or maybe you've lost your reference to `mainContainerView` (it is nil), so nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you need to call the view's setNeedsDisplay method to mark it for rerendering.